# Retrieving the default token symbol of an Ethereum network via json-rpc

Tags: json-rpc

How can I retrieve the default token symbol of an Ethereum network via json-rpc?

```
Ethereum would return "ETH"
Ethereum classic would return "ETC"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Web3's [`getChainId()`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.4/web3-eth.html#getchainid) to get the chain ID.

Then map the returned chain ID into the list of known networks from https://chainid.network/chains.json, where the currency symbol is in the `nativeCurrency` nested object.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, but the actual answer is it's not possible